# Can't point to a range in sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The code is the following:

```
Private Sub UnlockSheet()
    Range(Selection.Offset(640, 1), Selection.Offset(0, 0)).Select
    ' I've tried this

    Sheet1.Range(Selection.Offset(640, 1), Selection.Offset(0, 0)).Select
    ' I've tried this too

    Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    ws.Range(Selection.Offset(640, 1), Selection.Offset(0, 0)).Select
    ' and of course this, too
End Sub
```

This code - with any of the specified declaration - gives me error runtime error 1004.
Could someone explain me why? I can't get it. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/application-defined-or-object-defined-error) is unclear to me.

Comment: The first code line should work in any circumstances. Does it raise an error in your case? The second and the third will raise errors if **selection** is not made in `Sheet1`... And it is not mandatory that `Sheets(1)` to be the same with `Sheets1`, if somebody played with the sheet `CodeName` or moved the sheets...

Comment: Thanks Fane, nobody changed name or position to the sheet. I always prefer to link SheetN BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that

1. `Sheets(1)`
2. `Sheets("Sheet1")`
3. `Sheet1`

can be 3 totally different sheets. Excel uses 3 different naming systems to reference sheets and they are totally independent.

1. `Sheets(1)` uses the position in the tab bar of the sheet.
2. `Sheets("Sheet1")` uses the tab name of the sheet
3. `Sheet1` uses the VBA name of the sheet (that has nothing to do with the tab name!).

Also note that using `Range` without specifying a sheet makes Excec decide which sheet you mean. So if you want reliable code you **always** have to specify which sheet that range should be in.

You might benefit from reading
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

If you try to `.Select` a range that is not in the active sheet VBA will throw *"Runtime Error 1004"*. So you have to activate/select the sheet first. Also if `Selection` is not in the same sheet you try to select, it will fail too.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet  'This ensures that `Selection` and `ws` are in the same sheet.
ws.Range(Selection.Offset(640, 1), Selection).Select
```

Note that `.Offset(0, 0)` does not make any sense. So remove it.

Note that the best practice is not to use `.Select` at all. Unless you want the user to see that selection.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yea I know about avoid using select guide, since I've linked it in many other Q&A on SO. And I know first note too :) unfortunately, Excel won't link to sheet even if linked correctly (I always prefer to link SheetN for avoid name or position changes).

Comment: @Dovatti While it is good to reference to `SheetN` because it makes everything very reliable, it is not good working in combination with `Selection` because `Selection` always refers to `ActiveSheet`. So when ever you use `Selection` and you use `SheetN` as reference you need to make sure `SheetN` is the `ActiveSheet` otherwise in a statement like `Sheet1.Range(Selection.Offset(640, 1), Selection.Offset(0, 0))` the `Range` is in another sheet than the `Selection` and therefore this throws an error.

Comment: Yes that's right, but how could I avoid using `select` or `activate` in this case? I can't find the right way to avoid using it.

Comment: @Dovatti Hard to tell because you did not describe what you expect your code to do. If it really depends on the user to select something before running the code then as I showed is the only way and you have to use `Selection`. If it does not depend on the user to select something then you need to explain what you expect your code to do.

Comment: Don't worry: I've found a nice solution thanks to your explanation. Thanks again.